# Create an alarm between to different apps

Tags: android, alarmmanager, xposed

I want to create an alarm to create a notification.
The app that will create to Intent is not the same that will receive it.

I have that code, but it doesn't work, and I can't figure why :

First app:

```
package io.github.alucas.alarmsend;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Create alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final Intent intent = new Intent("io.github.alucas.alarmreceive.ALARM");
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 5, alarmIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Send alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Second app :

```
package io.github.alucas.alarmreceive;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receive alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="io.github.alucas.alarmreceive">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="io.github.alucas.alarmreceive.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="io.github.alucas.alarmreceive.ALARM"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[edit1]

Adding the flowing line fixed my problem :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```

Comment: The alarm will work only with your application. Why don't you receive the alarm and then call the other app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second application has no activity. If you add an activity to your second app, install and run on the device, your code will work and the alarm will be delivered to the second application.

Comment: Ok, I add an activity on the second App.
Now it work, but only when the second App is running. How can I fix that ? And why do I need an activity ?

Comment: According to the Android docs, the app should have one of four entry points: activity, service, content provider or broadcast receiver. But for some reason, apps without the activity (or the service) couldn't work and couldn't be even seen in the list of apps on the device. I didn't find any specs for that. So... we just have to accept that as an undocumented feature (or bug)... Anyway, the real app must have an activity to do some setups. By the way, you can also try to create a service.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the folowing line solved my problem :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```